# How can i join tables from two different servers on sybase?

Tags: sybase

In the SQL SERVER we can make a link between servers, or specify the server on the table name like:

```
Select Op.idUser,Op.Username,Op.item 

from

Opers Op Inner Join Sv2.PermissionSQL.Itens Itm on Itm.IdUser = Op.IdUser
```

how can we do something like this in Sybase ?

Answer (score 1):

In Sybase ASE, the concept of Linked Servers is accomplished via the CIS (Component Integration Service).  You can use it to add a connection to a remote server, and query as if it were local.

You need to add the remote server to your interfaces file, and then use the `sp_addserver` command to create the connection between the servers.  From there you can create either proxy tables, proxy databases or both.

This document covers [CIS for SAP ASE 16](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32702.1600/doc/pdf/ase_cis_users.pdf), but most of the setup is the same for earlier versions, just some of the supported features and databases may differ.